# Why am I having trouble sending requests to Google API's that have been authenticated through additional Firebase scopes?

Tags: firebase, authentication, next.js, google-api-js-client

I'm writing a next.js application that requires a user to log in using their Google account, and then I need to get a list of their calendar events, potentially adding events into their accounts too.

I have Firebase V9 working flawlessly using firebase/auth, which, upon successful Auth flow returns me a [user object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken) with a `getIdToken` method that should allow me to make API calls to Google Services outlined in the [additional scopes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk) section in the firebase login loop. Every time I make a call to the Calendar API, however, I'm getting a `401 invalid credentials` error.

I've found many resources

- [firebase-gapi](https://github.com/msukmanowsky/gapi-firebase)
- [accessToken not returned](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/294)
- ["Firebase does NOT provide OAuth2 scopes to other google services like Calendar"](https://fireship.io/snippets/how-to-use-google-apis-or-gapi-with-firebase-auth/)
- ["Use GAPI to login, not Firebase"](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-google-apis-with-firebase-auth-and-firebase-ui-on-the-web-46e6189cf571)

that outline that this isn't possible, but then, why should I be able to add additional scopes in the Firebase OAuth2 flow? What does that achieve?